# Django error deploying to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

Hey I'm new to heroku and django and I've been countering a problem while following those tutorials:
[Tutorial 1 - django girl](https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/heroku/index.html), [Tutorial 2-heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)

I was following all the steps to deploy an existing project to heroku and I keep getting this message:

```
    remote:      $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 302, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 43, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 99, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 104, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2231, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2214, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2201, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:        ImportError: No module named 'mysite.settings'
remote:
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote:
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote:
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mysitefp1.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mysitefp1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mysitefp1.git'
```

my wsgi.py:

```
    import os
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

    application = get_wsgi_application()
    application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)

my settings.py
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '************************'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!

DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="mysite.mysite.settings"


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'address',
    'BusinessApp',
    'BaseApp',
    'UserApp',
    'conversation',
    'django_libs',
    'widget_tweaks',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'), os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates', 'allauth')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]



# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

# auth and allauth settings
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
SITE_ID=1


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
    # os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media'),
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    # '/static/',
    # '',
]

import dj_database_url
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'BaseApp.adapters.ProfileAdapter'
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
LOGIN_URL = "/"


DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()

SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

DEBUG = False

try:
    from .local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass


STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

my procfile:

```
web: gunicorn mysite.wsgi --log-file -
```

my requirements.txt:

```
defusedxml==0.4.1
dj-database-url==0.4.1
Django==1.9.5
django-address==0.1.5
django-allauth==0.25.2
django-conversation==1.4.6
django-libs==1.67.4
django-oauth==1.1
django-staticfiles==1.2.1
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.1
gunicorn==19.4.5
oauthlib==1.1.1
Pillow==3.2.0
PyJWT==1.4.0
python-social-auth==0.2.19
python3-openid==3.0.10
requests==2.10.0
requests-oauthlib==0.6.1
six==1.10.0
whitenoise==3.0
psycopg2==2.5.4
```

I cant figure out what's happening for 3 days! please help me out

P.S If i try to disable static the same error happens again when i try to migrate.

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'mysite.settings'` does this file exist in your directory?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue the thing is that git somehow didn't added the settings file to the repository inside my project the way i solved this was to create a new django project and a new repository, also check if you have your settings file in the .gitignore file. always check which changes are going to be commited with git status if everything you need is in there then it should work.